# How to deal with scaling and transparency of a bitmap as android:windowBackground

Tags: android, background, bitmap

I am trying to set a global background image for my android application. The image is a PNG file with transparency. I set it in the following way:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_main</item>
</style>
```

And `drawable/background_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/background_main_bitmap"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" />
```

My PNG file should sit at the bottom of the screen always, being scaled to match the screen size always. With the above code, however, I am facing two problems.

1. The transparent background of the PNG file is black while I want it to be white.
2. The PNG file is larger than the screen width and hence, I can only see a portion of it. It is not scaled to match the width of the screen.

How can I accomplish these two things, possibly without havin to write Java code? (Although it would be better than nothing...)

Answer (score 1):

Problem #1 can be solved with a `layer-list` in `drawable/background_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/background_main_bitmap"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal|fill_horizontal" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Problem #2 remains though...

Comment: I don't have answer to #2, but the layered drawable may be written much easier: `<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" /><item android:drawable="@drawable/background_main_bitmap" />`

Answer (score 0):

just change the property of `android:gravity` like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/flush"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, using `layer-list` may give you expected [scaling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList):

> All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View, by default. Thus, placing your images in a layer list at different positions might increase the size of the View and some images scale as appropriate. To avoid scaling items in the list, use a `<bitmap>` element inside the `<item>` element to specify the drawable and define the gravity to something that does not scale, such as `"center"`

Thus, the following drawable will suit your request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_main_bitmap" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: That doesnt work, since window background is not a view. Just a drawable.